# How do I show that $\inf\limits_{\det(X)\neq0}\|X^{-1}AX\|^{2}_{F}=\sum\limits_{\lambda\in{\Lambda}}|\lambda|^{2}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Show that
$$\inf\limits_{\det(X)\neq 0}\|X^{-1}AX\|^2_F=\sum_{\lambda\in\Lambda}|\lambda|^{2}$$
holds, where $\Lambda(A)$ is the set containing all eigenvalues of A, and $\|\cdot\|_{F}$ is the Frobenius norm.

Also, I want to show that it is indeed the minimum if and only if $A$ is diagonalizable.

Comment: Maybe you could use $tr(M^T M)$ instead of $||M||_F^2$. It would prove the second part of your question. I'm still not sure about the first part.

Comment: Technically, $\Lambda(A)$ is not the set since the repeated eigenvalues would be there present only once and you must sum over the eigenvalues including their algebraic multiplicity. So either $\Lambda(A)$ should be a sort of sequence or the sum should include multipliers given by the algebraic multiplicities.

Comment: I think you will use density of diagonalizable matrices along with continuity somewhere

Comment: For the record, this particular question is an exercise that originated with Leonid Mirsky in his 1955 book "An Introduction to Linear Algebra".  Specifically, exercise 11 on page 428.  The exercise has been reused in other textbooks as well (e.g., Householder's "The Theory of Matrices in Numerical Analysis" and Stewart and Sun's "Matrix Perturbation Theory").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, there is a useful relation between eigenvalues and the Frobenius norm$\color{red}{^*}$:
$$
\sum_i|\lambda_i|^2\leq\|A\|_F^2,
$$
where $\lambda_i$ ($i=1,\ldots,n$) are the eigenvalues of $A$. Since for any nonsingular $X$, $X^{-1}AX$ has the same eigenvalues as $A$, we have
$$
\sum_i|\lambda_i|^2\leq\|X^{-1}AX\|_F^2.
$$
This gives us:

> For any nonsingular $X$ and $A$ with eigenvalues $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n$, 
>   $$\tag{1}
> \left(\sum_{i}|\lambda_i|^2\right)^{1/2}\leq\|X^{-1}AX\|_F.
> $$

Next, if $A$ is diagonalizable, it is easy to see that with $A=Y\Lambda Y^{-1}$, the equality in (1) is attained with $X=Y^{-1}$.

If $A$ is not diagonalizable, a proper scaling of the Jordan form helps here. We know that there is a nonsingular $Y$ and a Jordan matrix $J$ such that $A=YJY^{-1}$, where the Jordan blocks in $J$ have the form
$$
J_{\lambda}=\lambda I + N,
$$
where $N$ is zero elsewhere except ones on the first superdiagonal. Now take any $\epsilon>0$ and consider $D_{\epsilon}:=\mathrm{diag}(1,\epsilon,\ldots,\epsilon^{n-1})$ and observe that
$$
D_{\epsilon}^{-1}J_{\lambda}D_{\epsilon}=\lambda I + \epsilon N.
$$
This indicates that, by a proper diagonal similarity transformation, you can make the nilpotent part of $J_{\lambda}$ arbitrarily small and this applies also to the whole Jordan matrix. Summarizing:

> For any matrix $A$ and $\epsilon>0$, there is a nonsingular $Y$ such that
>   $$
> A=YJY^{-1}, 
> $$
>   where $J=\Lambda+N$, $\Lambda$ is diagonal (containing the eigenvalues of $A$ on the diagonal), and $N$ is such that $\|N\|_F\leq\epsilon$.

So, setting again $X=Y^{-1}$ in (1), you can make the right-hand side of the inequality arbitrarily close to the left-hand side. Nevertheless, the infimum is not attained if $A$ is not diagonalizable.

---

$\color{red}{^*}$ The fact that 
$$\sum_i|\lambda_i|^2\leq\|A\|_F^2$$
can be shown, e.g., using the Schur form. Let $A=QTQ^*$ be the Schur decomposition of $A$ where $Q$ is unitary and $T$ upper triangular with the eigenvalues $\lambda_i$ on the diagonal. Since the eigenvalues can come in any prescribed order on the diagonal of $\lambda_i$, say, the row/column $i$ of $T$ contains $\lambda_i$ on the diagonal. If $t_i$ is the $i$th column of $T$, we have hence $|\lambda_i|\leq\|t_i\|_2$. Therefore, $$\sum_i|\lambda_i|^2\leq\sum_i\|t_i\|_2^2=\mathrm{trace}(T^*T)=\|T\|_F^2=\|A\|_F^2.
$$